# Python PermissionError Errno 13 when creating file

Tags: python, intellij-idea, permissions, virtualenv

I am using IntelliJ, a virtual environment and Python 3.7
My system is running MacOS Mojave.

My user account has admin and I have checked the directories for the project - all have read+write permissions.

Now, when I run my script:

```
if(len(clean_text.split(' ')) > min_word_count):
    with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(clean_text)
```

I get `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: <file_path>.txt`

Could this be something to do with using a Virtual Environment?
Does my VenV need to be running as admin? If so, how? I cannot chmod the file... because it does not exist until I try to create it - but that does not work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Okay... I found that the issue was that the file path was for a different user (there are more than one user profile on this Mac)...

Comment: That's strange. You should've got a different error - but still get an error ;) because `w` is write only, while `w+` is a write that creates the file it it doesn't exist. Try `w+` anyway.

Comment: @h4z3 Thanks - tried `w+` but I get the same error.

Comment: @h4z3 I found the issue. It as my own stupidity. Updated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hahahah, no problem. I sometimes confuse my paths as well.